# Highcharts: Need a continous vertical line on x- axis to act somewhat like scroller

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to have a continous vertical red line on x-axis for multiple charts, such that when I put the finger tip over it and drag towards left or right, it should move the graph(left or right, respectively) And when it passes over some data points it should show the data values as well. Is this possible to implement with highcharts?
Please Help!

Comment: Everything is possible.. just depends how much time you have. I would try to use Highstock with navigator: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume - there you can drag&drop/slide on the plotting area to move graph. It also implements two panes, in your case similar to multiple chart.

Comment: Thanks for helping Pawel, I have 2 days time.

Comment: For reference - http://jsfiddle.net/bxvoo7uq/2/
I need a vertical line..somewhat like this. This is an example of amcharts but I need to implement it in highcharts along with extra feature of dragging the chart when we go towards right/left.

Comment: I think you are referring simply [`tooltip.crosshairs`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.crosshairs) in Highcharts. It works a bit different than the one in amcharts.

Comment: Yes, crosshairs won't fullfill my requirement because when I am clicking on data points then only it's showing vertical line & it is not movable as well (in my android device). I want this vertical-movable line even if only one data point is there.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2kLt0eck/1/ ? Note: tooltip in Highcharts is displayed only when hovering point. If you want different one, then utilize [that demo](http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/latlon-advanced).

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something like this, thanks :-) it will help me in implementation of what I am looking for. What I need is a single line for multiple graphs(of different div's)

Comment: I implemented crosshairs (with snap:false). Its working fine in desktop but not working properly in my android application(Line is not moving properly with fingertip).

Comment: Do you have jsFiddle demo? I will check it.

Comment: demo - http://jsfiddle.net/achG4/29/

Comment: The second example doesn't work because it's Highstock, where panning & pinching is enabled by default. Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/achG4/31/

Comment: I need to move the vertical line of both the graphs together. And Secondly these vertical lines are moving fine on mouseover in jsfiddle but not working smoothly in my android application. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Probably your app is using webview, which isn't master of the performance (as I know). Have you considered using just one graph with multiple panes, instead of two separate? Like [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume).

Comment: Actually I already implemented multiple graphs separately. So again implementing will be time consuming.

Comment: Then the best I can suggest is to use plotLines: use mousemove event and there add/remove plotLine at specific places. `toValue()` method will be very helpful.

Comment: okay. I will check if it helps.